# UIWebView in UITableView hide cells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiwebview, resize

I have a `UIWebView` in `UITableView`, I have this on storyboard:

[image: Storyboard design]

The `UIImageView` is my future NavBar and the `UIWebView` is in the `UITableView`, I have this configuration:

- -`UIImageView`
- -`UITableView`
- - - -`UIWebView`
- - - -`UITableViewCell`

When the `UIWebView` load the pages (I have local pages) I want that it takes dynamically their size and for this I have this code:

```
[detailWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.,0.,detailWebView.frame.size.width,[[detailWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] intValue])];
```

The problem is when the loaded page is long, my `UIWebBrowser` hide the cells and didn't push them to get cells at the bottom.
I don't understand why I have this, when I resize the `UIWebBrowser` in the storyboard I don't have this problem but I want to do it programmatically

Thanks,

Comment: try adding the `UIWebView` inside an `UITableViewCell`

Comment: XCode tell me «Illegal connection», I don't how to do but I think if I can move cells I'll solve the problem

Comment: you can try changing your "parent" `UITableView` to `Static Cells` with two cells, in the first one put your web view and in the second one another `UITableView` with `Dynamic Prototypes`, this is a little tricky but maybe it works

Comment: Yes but I want to have just on scroll in the screen and not scrolled TableView independent of the screen, I don't know if you understand what I mean

Comment: yes, I get it, the other option is to add the web view by code in the first row of the table

Comment: It's not elegant, why when I resize my webView in the storyboard my cells moves automatically and when I do it programmatically it's not the same? Is there an alternative for setFrame: ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20349/discussion-between-tkanzakic-and-belkadam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to tkanzakic, I solved the problem by adding an empty cell at the beginning, and changing their heigh

heigh of the 1st cell = old webView.heigh - actual webView.heigh

To change the heigh of cell I used `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath`
And no need to reload all data of the tableView I just use this:

```
NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
[detailsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```